# How to change programatically default server Play + Ebean in runtime

Tags: java, oracle, playframework, database-connection, ebean

I need to change of connection in runtime. I have this servers configurations:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//178.20.26.25:1521/orcl"
db.default.user="TEST1"
db.default.password="test1"

db.test.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
db.test.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//178.20.26.26:1521/orcl"
db.test.user="TEST"
db.test.password="test"

ebean.default="models.*"
ebean.test="models.*"
```

I'm trying with this method but give me `RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?` in `EbeanServerFactory.create(c);`

```
public static void ChangeConfig(){
    ServerConfig c = new ServerConfig();
    c.setName("test");

    c.loadFromProperties();

    c.setDefaultServer(true);
    c.setRegister(true);

    EbeanServerFactory.create(c);
}
```

I'm not sure that this method do the thing, but it is what i find.
What could be the cause of this error? Is there other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should state what you are trying to achieve (the problem you face and why you want to adopt the strategy of changing the default server). I suspect you might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found other way of solve my problem using `EbeanServer` class. This not change the default server but let you use the model for an specific server. For example:

```
EbeanServer defserver = Ebean.getServer("test");
```

Cause of this I did a lot of modifications in my code, for example this line:

```
Activity.find.all(); //Get all activities in the default server
```

I changed it by:

```
defserver.find(Activity.class).findList(); //Get all activities in server "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because DataSourceConfig is not loading from properties file.

You can create it in your ChangeConfig method. To do this add following code:

```
DataSourceConfig ds = new DataSourceConfig();
ds.setDriver("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//178.20.26.26:1521/orcl");
ds.setUsername("TEST");
ds.setPassword("test");
c.setDataSourceConfig(ds);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what i'm trying is to change the default server instance of ebean by other server instance (`test` in this case) in runtime, definitely my `ChangeConfig` method don't solve the problem. Sorry if my question wasn't clear. Please check edit. Thanks